# offcanvas menu link broken

Tags: canvas, joomla, menu, woothemes

I'm working on a project for school, and I'm having an issue that I hope someone will be able to help with (and possibly curb my festering hatred for joomla, but that's beside the point :)

First, here's the URL: http://edcc3.cloudaccess.net

The issue is, when you resize the browser or use an emulator to see the rendering on 480px devices, the offcanvas menu links won't work. Meaning they don't scroll to the targetted sections within the one page layout, and I cant figure out why. I'm betting it's an ordering issue but for the life of me I can't find the problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a menu extension or the core menu or does the template have some custom js?  The html looks okay.  Why do you think it's an ordering issue?

Comment: As @Elin said, the HTML markup is fine. There is an anchor, however this is the default action for UIKit's offcanvas menu. You might need to write a small custom script which closes the offcanvas menu and navigates down to the specified element on click.

Comment: @Elin I thought it might be that the offcanvas code is at the bottom of the markup, and maybe because of that it couldn't "see" my anchor tags due to .....hierarchy....voodoo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I've written a small example for you which I've tested and works:

**HTML:**

```
<a id="test" href="#test" data-uk-smooth-scroll="">Item</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#test').on('click', function() { 
    $.UIkit.offcanvas.hide();
});
```

The above jQuery code, detects a click on the defined ID of the menu item and closes the offcanvas display. The anchor/scroll will then kick in.

Do note that as this is Joomla, you may have to perform a Template Override for the menu, which Yootheme have already done.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a go and report back

Comment: Well, Apparently I need to read up more on creating overrides, because I'm a little fuzzy on how to implement this. Accepted as the answer though, because looking at the code, there's no reason why it wouldn't work :)