# Joomla Offcanvas Menu Error

Tags: joomla, off-canvas-menu

How do I get my main menu to work on my mobile phone? I had some "offcanvas" module error that I tried to resolve.

When I click on a link on the homepage on my mobile phone, this error appears

> Publish modules to the "offcanvs" position.

" Spelled like that. "Offcanvs". Without an "a".
[image]
This issue is described 3 years ago [offcanvas menu link broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349827/offcanvas-menu-link-broken)
but I can't understand, I am new in Joomla.

Please Help me!

Comment: Are you using a Gantry 5 template?

Comment: Thank you. I am using "JD Magazine" template.